# Can I use nuget packages for octopus scriptcs deploy script?

Tags: powershell, nuget, octopus-deploy, scriptcs

I would like to use functionality contained in a nuget package in one of my octopus scriptcs deploy scripts. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke some code from dll contained in deployed NuGet packages, you can it in the following way:
1. Add your Octopus packages destination folder as a local NuGet repository to scriptcs. For that place in scriptcs folder nuget.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="LocalFeed"
         value="C:\Octopus\Packages\" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

2. Run (from PowerShell for example) `scriptsc -install <package_name>`
3. Then you can use libraries in your C# script:

   ```
   using MyLib;
   Console.WriteLine("Hello");
   ```

Comment: I don't need to use a nuget package I've created, but one hosted on nuget in an octopus deploy script, is this still valid?

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of standard scripts you can add to your package, which will be executed during deployment:

1. `PreDeploy.<ext>`
2. `Deploy.<ext>`
3. `PostDeploy.<ext>`
4. `DeployFailed.<ext>`

These can be either PowerShell, ScriptCS, or Bash (subject to them running on the appropriate environment - Windows for PowerShell and ScriptCS or Linux for Bash).

You can read more about [Custom Scripts on the Octopus Deploy website](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Custom+scripts).

Comment: Right so here's what I'm doing now, In a ps script, I install chocolatey, cinst scriptcs, scriptcs -install <NugetPackage>;

Then I run a C# script attempting to use that package, to an explosion